# python pandas unable to display summary of large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I recently upgraded to pandas version 0.13 and am experiencing this problem where no matter how big my dataframe is ( the biggest one has 25 columns and 158430 rows), pandas prints out the entire dataframe (well not the entire thing, just a few rows in each column but it's still messy!) instead of printing out the summary table which is much cleaner in the case of such large data frames. I was just wondering whether anyone else is having this problem or has had this problem in the past and knows how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the change in the [what's new](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#dataframe-repr-changes) for .13.

The old way was to print the result of `df.info()`. You can change the behavior to always do that with `set_option('display.large_repr', 'info')`. You can add that to your IPython startup file if you're using IPython.

Comment: Just as a comment, I remember hearing that the `.info()` summary view was a stumbling block for a lot of newcomers to pandas.

Comment: Great thanks for this. Although the reason they provided does make sense I don't think its reasonable to maintain the same display behavior for small and large data frames as it causes more confusion and clutter on the screen thereby overwhelming beginners who are dealing with large dataFrames.