# Where did the Dataframe summary view gone on pandas 0.13?

Tags: pandas

Installed 0.13 a few days ago, and now when Im calling a big dataframe, instead of summery view I get the entire dataframe plotted. I saw that 0.13.1 is released no download link is available on the site. is this a bug? (both  of the problems)

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/getpandas.html is refreshed....didn't update the link

Comment: For the summary view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737988/python-pandas-unable-to-display-summary-of-large-dataframe/21739515#21739515

Comment: Thanks guys, that's was helpful :)